find parts of /dev/sda3 consuming space
'df -h' tells me that /dev/sda3 has only 8 percent space free of total 120GB. So I want to free some space in it.
My main directory where I put my stuff is only 4gb(part of /dev/sda3). So it means some other  parts of /dev/sda3 are consuming the space.
How do I find those parts and free space?
Edit: Result of 'df -h':


Stop concerning yourself with the device (/dev/sda3), rather look at the filesystem (where /dev/sda3 is mounted). Use du -sk /mountpoint/* to start.

No such file or directory...when i run du -sk...

Please update the question with the output of df -h

@SorenA, output added.

So your root-filesystem (/) is almost full. As @waltinator suggested, run du -sk / to see which directories or files that are large (usually /var or /home) then cd to that directory, run du -sk * and so on, until you know what takes up the space. You could also run  sudo ncdu / for an easier overview - select and press enter on largest libary to drill down

use ncdu it will visually lists you the folders that are taking up the space

The command du will help figure out where that space is used.  I haven't had much luck using the command as described in previous comments.  For me it's been better to change directories to be at the place where the du command should start and always specify "." which I take to mean "from this spot"  Example:
cd /    #be at the system root

du . >~/size.txt    # this is huge and the output is directed to your area as size.txt

